# Override onItemCheckedStateChanged() in AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener

Tags: java, android

Here is the code:

```
    mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    mListView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean
                checked) {
        }

        @Override
        private boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.cam_menu, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.menu_item_delete_reminder:
                    for (int nC = mCursorAdapter.getCount() - 1; nC >= 0; nC--) {
                        if (mListView.isItemChecked(nC)) {
                            mDbAdapter.deleteReminderById(getIdFromPosition(nC));
                        }
                    }
                    mode.finish();
                    mCursorAdapter.changeCursor(mDbAdapter.fetchAllReminders());
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        }
    });
}
```

This is an example from book 'Learn Android Studio' by Gerber and Craig. I get an error:  is not abstract and does not override abstract method onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode,int,long,boolean) in MultiChoiceModeListener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alt + Enter (in Android Studio) imports
    `import android.support.v7.view.ActionMode;`
I changed it to
    `android.view.ActionMode`

Found information here:
https://forums.bignerdranch.com/t/multichoicemodelistener-problem/6106